# Receiving a TypeError when executing a Redux action using Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

These are actions in sessionActions:

```
// Absolute imports
import axios from 'axios';

// Relative imports
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import auth from '../auth/authenticator';
import { ROOT_URL } from './constants';

export function loginUser(formValues) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/login`, formValues)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .error((response) => {
        dispatch(loginFailure(response.data));
      });
  }
}

export function loginSuccess(user) {
  return {
    type: types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  };
}

export function loginFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: types.LOG_IN_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  };
}
```

And when I trigger the action I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: _axios2.default.post(...).then(...).error is not a function`

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong... additional info below:

`"axios": "^0.15.3",`

I have been stuck here all day and can't seem to find any information that will guide me to a solution...

Posting my sessionReducer as well:

```
// Absolute imports
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// Relative imports
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const INITIAL_STATE = { user: null, status: null, error: null, loading: false };

export default function sessionReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  let error;

  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
      browserHistory.push('/dashboard');
      return { ...state, user: action.payload.user, status: 'authenticated', error: null, loading: false };

    case types.LOG_IN_FAILURE:
      error = action.payload.data || { message: action.payload.message };
      return { ...state, user: null, status: 'sign-in', error: error, loading: false };

    case types.LOG_OUT:
      return { ...state, user: null, status: 'logout', error: null, loading: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I should also note that I am able to throw in a debugger at multiple points in this process and see the correct payload being returned. Just can't figure out why the error is occurring and stopping the whole process.

Comment: Are you using a middleware?

Comment: @UG_ - redux thunk import thunk from 'redux-thunk'; / applyMiddleware(thunk)

Comment: basically "error" is not a function. From viewing axios API docs, I don't see this. Did you try "catch" instead of "error"? That's what's used in the Axios README file.

Comment: @aarosil - yup... that was it... I'm an idiot. Please post as an answer so I can accept and up vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This TypeError means "error" isn't a function - which is exactly the problem.

You can chain with `catch` function to catch errors, there is no `error` function.

Details can be seen here in API doc for  [Handling Errors](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors)

Answer (score 0):

In your action creators you're using the constant `types.SIGNIN_USER_SUCCESS,` and `type: types.SIGNIN_USER_FAILURE,` where in your reducer you're using the constants `types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:` and `case types.LOG_IN_FAILURE:`. These don't match thus an error will be thrown. I am assuming you didn't mean to do this.

Comment: I think that will still work, if constants in action creator are well defined, just that it wont be caught in reducer.

Comment: I updated and still hit the same error, unfortunately. Thanks for the spot though! Staring at the same problem for hours leads to silly mistakes like that!

Comment: @UG_3 that makes sense. @Noah No problem. I had this same issue once and it was this exact issue I pointed above. I apologize that my answer didn't work. I don't have much experience with axios but based on the documentation the function `catch` is used where you're using `error`. Try changing this? The error is saying `error` is not a function. Everything in your code looks fine to me.